# Is the receiving team more likely to win a overtime?

Tags: american-football, statistics, nfl

As I learned, one part of the overtime rules is:

> If the receiving team scores a touchdown on the first drive, said team will win.

It sounds unfair to me, as it's likely that both teams could do that, if they get the chance.

Is there a statistic about the chances to touchdown in the first drive versus scoring on the second drive in a NFL game?

Clarifications:

- Statistics may only count overtime or any drive after kickoff.
- Of course that statistics should not be restricted to Super Bowls.
- With "first drive" and "second drive", I mean drives after a kickoff.
- I'm specifically asking about touchdowns not field goals, because field goals are not relevant to that rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally answerable considering the probability of winning given the coin toss; I haven't seen anyone modelling specifically the chance of taking the opening kick for a TD. That's because that is not the only factor at hand in the overtime consideration; a proper evaluation needs to consider the entirety of the outcomes of overtime in order to evaluate whether it favors the receiving team.

As of [late 2015](http://www.espn.com/blog/statsinfo/post/_/id/112875/numbers-dont-back-up-patriots-ot-strategy), the receiving team had won slightly more than half of the time (50.7%) since the new overtime rules (allowing a drive after a made FG - it used to be even a made FG ended the overtime).  ESPN estimated a 53.8% chance overall (likely higher than observed when you control for the already-extant likelihoods, specifically the better team being already more likely to win).

In 2014, in a [blog post at the Harvard Sports Analysis Collective](http://harvardsportsanalysis.org/2014/01/modeling-nfl-overtime-as-a-markov-chain/), an analysis was done to determine the odds of winning an overtime game based on a Markov chain analysis.  Among other things, it noted that a drive from a kickoff ends in a touchdown about 20% of the time; this was before the adjustment to the touchback distance, though, so I would not necessarily take this as correct for 2016 and beyond. I'm also skeptical that you can consider an early game drive similarly to a late game drive or OT; a lot of information has changed hands by that point, leading both sides to have some opportunities to improve - but perhaps one more than the other; and further, defenses are tired (and while both sides may be tired, it seems to hurt defenses more than offenses overall).

---

If you want to look solely at the *outcomes*, well, there have been fewer than 100 overtime games since 2012, so it shouldn't be too hard to just count them?